# Capture the current value in ComboBox. wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, combobox, wxpython

In the code below I am trying to capture the current value of the ComboBox when the Save button is clicked.

Ive defined the function that is triggerd by the EVT_BUTTON that captures the values in the TextCtrl fields but does not work for ComboBox.

I've tried  a few different approaches such as just trying to assign to audit_engineer = self.engineer_name.

Can anyone help me?

Regards
Paul.

```
class CreateAudit(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label = "Site Name :", pos=(20,60))
        self.site_name = wx.TextCtrl(self, value = "Enter site name here.", pos=(150, 60), size=(140,-1))
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label = "Job Number", pos=(20,120))
        self.job_number = wx.TextCtrl(self, value = "4 digit number only.", pos=(150, 120), size=(140,-1))

        con = sqlite3.connect("hs_audit.sqlite")
        con.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
        myList = con.execute('SELECT engineer FROM T1').fetchall()
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Select Engineer :", pos=(20,180))
        self.engineer_name = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(150, 180), size=(140,-1)).SetItems(myList)

        self.save_button =wx.Button(self, label="Save", pos=(150, 400))
        self.save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.save_details)
        self.Show()

    def save_details(self, event):
        audit_site = self.site_name.GetValue()
        audit_engineer = self.engineer_name.GetValue() #<-- DOES NOT WORK NONE VALUE ERROR
        audit_jobnumber = self.job_number.GetValue()
        print audit_site
        print audit_engineer
        print audit_jobnumber
```

Comment: After further tinkering it seems that self.engineer_name is equal to None and this causes python to throw error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetCurrentSelection'".  How do I get the current value in the dropdown box then?

Comment: You already found out that for your ``self.engineer_name = …`` you got not the return you expected. Ask yourself what is the difference for the return value between ``… = class()`` and ``… = class().some_method()``.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
self.engineer_name = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(150, 180), size=(140,-1)).SetItems(myList)
```

to

```
self.engineer_name = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(170, 180), size=(170,-1), choices = myList)
```

Did the trick. Over complicated syntax in first effort I think.
Fixing these little things takes an age, but I'm enjoying the learning curve.